# GraalVM JavaScript suffers from "host access" issues

Tags: javascript, java, graalvm, graaljs

This is done with JavaScrupt interpreter shell of GraalVM CE 21.3.0.

Attempting to access some Java class, such as `java.io.File` results in this error:

```
TypeError: Access to host class java.io.File is not allowed or does not exist.
```

When running the shell without any options this much is needed to get the error:

```
new java.io.File()
```

When running the shell with `--js.java-package-globals=false` only this much is required:

```
Java.type("java.io.File")
```

How do I fix this problem? If these features are supposed to be provided, then why aren't they working right out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are missing the `--jvm` flag to run the `js` launcher in `jvm` mode which is required for Java interop.

```
$ ./graalvm-ee-java11-21.3.0/bin/js --eval 'new java.io.File(""); console.log("OK!")'
TypeError: Access to host class java.io.File is not allowed or does not exist.
        at <js> :program(Unknown)

$ ./graalvm-ee-java11-21.3.0/bin/js --jvm --eval 'new java.io.File(""); console.log("OK!")'
OK!
```

This is documented [here](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/js/JavaInteroperability/):

> To enable Java interoperability, the --jvm option has to be provided
> to the native launcher

Comment: Then why would `Java.type` or `java` even be provided in native mode?